# UIButton with both image and text possible?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uibutton

I have a button of size width 200 and height 270. I want to have text and image on the same button. Not as a background image on that text. Instead of this, I want to display the text with height 120 and image of height 150 on the same button. How to do it?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can use this code,it will serve your purpose

```
.h file code
IBOutlet UIButton *testBtn;

.m file code
[testBtn setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image name.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[testBtn setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(70.0, -150.0, 5.0, 5.0)];
[testBtn setTitle:@"Your text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Adjust the coordinates and size of your button as your requirement.This is a sample code to guide you.

PS:Take a UIButton in the nib file>Make it a custom button>Connect the IBOutlet to your custom button in the nib file.Thats it.

Comment: hi aditya thanks for answering my question. I tried it.Code works perfectly but one problem is my image is not the fixed size.How to set image size so that it can be fit to button size?

Comment: This can also be done directly in the NIB file as well, which allows you to preview how it will look without having to experiment with it in code.

Comment: For those who need to make the button in code, you would adjust the image by setting testBtn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right);

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I had to overwrite layoutSubviews as posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201959/label-under-image-in-uibutton

Comment: the solution which worked instantly for me was posted here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5358259/2207018

Answer (score 15):

The below code shows placing an image and text in a button using setImageEdgeInsets and setTitleEdgeInsets properties of UIButton class.

```
UIButton *butt=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom ];
    [butt setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [butt setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sig.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [butt setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0)];
    [butt setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(75.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
    [butt setTitle:@"hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [butt setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:butt];
```

Comment: This didn't work for me until I changed setBackgroundImage to setImage and then it worked great.

Comment: background image and image are different

Comment: I think the question is how to set an image along with a title and not how to set the background image along with a title

Answer (score 7):

**In Swift 3**

```
let button = UIButton()

//make sure the image (jpg, png) you are placing in the button
//is about the right size or it will push the label off the button

//add image
let image = UIImage(named:"my_button_image")
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top:0, left:-30, bottom:0, right:0) //adjust these to have fit right

//add title
button.setTitle("Fan", for: .normal)
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top:0, left:10, bottom:0, right:0) //adjust insets to have fit how you want

//add button to your view - like in viewDidLoad or your own custom view setup
addSubview(button)
```

Don't forget to set anchors if doing so programmatically for it to appear/attach it to your button reference in Interface Builder if using a storyboard

Answer (score 6):

Use the concept of subviews. Take 3 controls, `UIButton` (200x270), `UILabel` (200x120) and `UIImageView` (200x150). Assign the image to the `UIImageView` and set the text for the `UILabel`. Position your label and imageview controls based upon the (x,y) location of the `UIButton`.

In the end, you should have something like:

For the following instances:

```
UIButton *button;
UILabel *label;
UIImageView *imageView;

[button addSubView:imageView];
[button addSubView:label];
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can display an image and a title in the same button, as long as they are both small enough to fit. The hard part comes, when you need to deal with placement.

You can play with the `contentVerticalAlignment` and `contentHorizontalAlignment` properties of the `UIButton` (inherited from `UIControl`).

You can also use the `titleEdgeInsets` and `imageEdgeInsets` properties to shift the the title and image from the placement they get based on the alignment properties.

If you want very accurate or custom placement, I suggest overriding the `titleRectForContentRect:` and `imageRectForContentRect:` methods of the `UIButton`. These allow you to define the frames for your title and image, and they are called whenever the button needs to be laid out. One warning, if you want to reference `self.titleLabel` inside of `titleRectForContentRect:`, make sure `self.currentTitle` is defined first. I was getting a bad access error, , possibly the method is called when first initializing the titleLabel.

Answer (score 5):

```
[testBtn setBackgroudImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image name.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[testBtn setTitle:@"Your text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: The user was looking for a way to do this without a background image

Answer (score 2):

swift version:

```
var button = UIButton()

newGameButton.setTitle("Новая игра", for: .normal)
newGameButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "energi"), for: .normal)
newGameButton.backgroundColor = .blue
newGameButton.imageEdgeInsets.left = -50
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have more control over the layout, create a subclass of `UIControl` and arrange the views you want (`UILabel`, `UIImageView`) in a xib file. Then you can use Autolayout regularly without having to sort out `UIEdgeInsets`.

Answer (score 0):

Using button subviews worked for me in Swift 4.

- Create your button
- Set an image for button
- Create a label for the text
- Add the label as a subview of your button
- Constrain the label within the button

  ```
         let imageAndTextButton : UIButton = {
              let button = UIButton(frame: .zero)
              button.tintColor = .clear
              button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "buttonImage"), for: .normal)
              button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleToFill
              button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
              return button
          }()
          let textForButtonLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
          textForButtonLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
          textForButtonLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Text For Button", attributes: buttonTextAttributes)
          textForButtonLabel.textAlignment = .center
          textForButtonLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
          imageAndTextButton.addSubview(textForButtonLabel)
          imageAndTextButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textForButtonLabel, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageAndTextButton, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
          imageAndTextButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textForButtonLabel, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageAndTextButton, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's work for me ,

We have to set value of **UIEdgeInsets** base on our button size and requirement .

```
[self.testButton setTitle: @"myTitle" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *iconImage = [UIImage imageWithIcon:@"fa-dot-circle-o" backgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor] iconColor:[UIColor whiteColor] fontSize:10.0f];

//UIEdgeInsets insets = {top, left, bottom, right};

[self.testButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3.0, 0.0, 3.0, 2.0)];
[self.testButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0)];
[self.testButton setImage:iconImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(testButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:self.testButton];
```

Hope This will help for some one .