# Unable to set Title of UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uibutton

I am new to iPhone,

```
    xpos=30;
    ypos=40;

for(int i=0;i<[MyArray count];i++)
        {            
            if(i!=0)
            {
                if (i%4==0) 
                {                    
                    ypos+=180;
                    xpos=30;
                }
                else
                {
                    xpos+=200;
                }
            }
            
            button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(xpos, ypos, 110.0, 130.0);
            [button setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"ibook2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(ypos, xpos, 0.0, 0.0)];
            [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [MyArray objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

i am able to see button but unable to see my text on the UIButton.

**Any help will be appreciated.**

[image]

Comment: I think your text on the button is not visible because of your xpos and ypos. It may be out of focus.

Comment: remove this > [button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(ypos, xpos, 0.0, 0.0)];   and try agian.

Comment: Your title insets seem to be much bigger than the size of the button. That gives you no available pixels for the title inside te button.

Comment: No all is because of setImage function. See my reply. Inset could be issue but real issue is not that one.

Comment: Well, we can set title and image both in a uibutton.. thats not an issue.

Comment: @waheeda: Of course you can set but not with using setImage function. if you want both things then you have to set image as a background of button. Check below comments of Krunal that issue is partially fixed but now issue is in text wrapping.

Comment: @Armaan: :) just FYI,  we CAN set title along with image in a button (and with setImage method), I have done it many times.  here is the proof: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344847/iphone-sdk-uibutton-with-both-image-and-text-possible

Comment: @waheeda:really thankful to you. You taught me something new :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please set buttons background image.You have set buttons image.
Please use this:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_button.png"]
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

For Wrapping button title User:

```
[button setTitle:@"Test button name 123" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 button.titleLabel.numberOfLines=2;

 button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

Comment: I tried using `setBackgroundImage` it is working fine but text is getting wrapped, i do not want wrapping.

Comment: I have edited code for set button title in two lines.set button size same as image size.

Comment: set button.tag=i; and when button click event get tag.
NSLog(@"%@",[MyArray objectAtIndex:btn.tag]);

Comment: better you change the font size to samaller and if you dont want wrappeing of text then remove the line button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

Answer (score 2):

You can't see the text because you have used setImage: function of button. At a time you can display image or button on text but you can add image as a background so you can see both image and tittle. In short set image as a background.

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Please also remove the line of setting inset.

Comment: I tried using `setBackgroundImage` it is working fine but text is getting wrapped, i do not want wrapping.

Comment: unable to see due to cyber roam :)

Comment: i tried this also, button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(xpos, ypos, 110.0, 130.0);
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ibook2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

Comment: i am not sure why your image is looks like squeeze and text is going outside of the button.

Comment: booklbl = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xpos, ypos, 70, 80)]autorelease];
            booklbl.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
     booklbl.numberOfLines = 0;
            booklbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];      
            booklbl.text =@"222";[button addSubview:booklbl];
             [self.view addSubview:button];

Comment: Why are you adding label into button there is already built in button available. ex. btn.titleLabel. One more thing you should have to calculate dynamic frame of label according to text.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then setting

```
[button setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"ibook2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];   // This will not allow you to set Button title.
```

You have to use :

```
[button setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"ibook2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    // This will allow you to set title along background button image.
```

Comment: I tried using `setBackgroundImage` it is working fine but text is getting wrapped, i do not want wrapping.

Comment: @Krunal : Can you please post the screen shot ?

Comment: @Krunal:Might be your text length will be bigger that your button width.

Comment: @Krunal : Your text are longer then the button width.

Answer (score 0):

if you image is too big then it will only show the image and text get truncated due to image as text will be visible after image, try using setBackground image or try small resolution image or setImageEdgeInsets .