# Title on button is hidden with setImage but is visible with setBackgroundImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm attempting to use imageEdgeInsets but imageEdgeInsets only works with setImage not setbackgroundimage.  My problem is when using setImage, the title of my image becomes hidden.

Is their a way to use imageEdgeInsets with setbackgroundimage OR having the title visible when using setImage

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear possible to use imageEdgeInsets with backgroundImage.

If you want `Image` and `Title` visible inside the `UIButton` but not overlapping use `imageEdgeInset` and `titleEdgeInset` with offset positions.  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344847/iphone-sdk-uibutton-with-both-image-and-text-possible)

If you want the title to appear on top of the `Image` use a separate UILabel constrained to UIButton.

**Suggestion:** next post, state what result you want in Question