# iPhone - Image not align at center on UIButton

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uiimage

I have customized UIButton with the following properties:

1. 84x44 frame
2. 84x44 background image
3. 32*32 image that should be centered

but my image is always aligned to the left. How can I align it back to center position on the UIButton?

I have a title on my button that is hidden (clearColor). These titles are key_value in a dictionary so I know which button is pressed and return corresponding value in the dictionary.
I now understand that it's these text that is pushing my image sideway, but how do I fix that?

Under attribute inspector,
there is a tap named Edge, set to Image.
I set left value as 22
and all image align to center.
Can someone explain to me how this works?

Comment: Maybe a repeated question : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564621/aligning-text-and-image-on-uibutton-with-imageedgeinsets-and-titleedgeinsets

Comment: I do have text (title) on my button, but they are suppose to be hidden for identification purpose

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check that your `titleLabel` is blank - if it has text, it will push the `image` to the left to make room for the `titleLabel` on the right.

Comment: Absolutely this. Strange and unintuitive that adding an Image to the UIButton changes my (previously Blue) text to White. White text was hidden on the White button, so I wasn't able to see the text that was pushing the image out of center.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me too. But one extra piece of advice for the new Xcoders: you have to backspace out the title AND hit return. I wondered why this didn't work the 1st time - that was why.