# How do I put the image on the right side of the button and the text align left

Tags: ios, uibutton, xcode6, imageedgeinsets

I have a `UIButton` with image and text. How do I align the image to the right, and align the text to the left?

Comment: There are a couple of good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4564621/2274694

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBDesignable class RightImageButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var alignImageToRight: Bool = true

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if alignImageToRight {
            if let imageView = self.imageView, let titleLabel = self.titleLabel {
                let imageWidth = imageView.frame.size.width
                var imageFrame: CGRect = imageView.frame;
                var labelFrame: CGRect = titleLabel.frame;
                labelFrame.origin.x = self.titleEdgeInsets.left + self.contentEdgeInsets.left
                imageFrame.origin.x = frame.width - self.imageEdgeInsets.right - self.contentEdgeInsets.right - imageWidth
                imageView.frame = imageFrame;
                titleLabel.frame = labelFrame;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below two methods

```
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
```

Pass value for left and right and adjust it.
Set offset as per you requirement.