# UIButton query in swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, xcode6

I have a button which is set at 62,62 square. 
I have an image which is 40,40 square.

I want the image in the button (which is easy and done), but I want it at the top of the button frame and I want some text at the bottom. So it looks like this :

[image]

Any idea how to do this in swift ?

I have got so far :

```
button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.13, green: 0.48, blue: 0.81, alpha: 1.0)
button.tag = i
button.imageView?.image
button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
button.setTitle("Test", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

The test setTitle, comes to the right of the image as ... form. 
Anyone can advise ?

Comment: `imageEdgeInsets` and `titleEdgeInstets` properties of `UIButton` seems to be what you're looking for. Another topic about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564621/aligning-text-and-image-on-uibutton-with-imageedgeinsets-and-titleedgeinsets (which could be I think easily translated in Swift)

Comment: Cheers Larme, will have a look!

Answer (score 0):

Using the interface builder;

- set the image to the Background property of the button. Using code it is `button.setBackgroundImage`
- from Control section set the horizontal alignment of the text to Bottom. Using code it is
  `button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentBottom`