# Remove vertical and bottom offset when configuring titleLabel for UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

Please consider following code:

```
let addTo: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        btn.titleLabel?.font = Theme.Font.sixteen.reqular
        btn.setTitle(LocalizedStrings.addTo.value, for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(Theme.Color.blue, for: .normal)
        btn.contentVerticalAlignment = .top
        btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
        btn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        return btn
    }()
```

[image]

What i want is, to remove top and bottom spacing. Because i want to configure it manually.

I went [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564621/aligning-text-and-image-on-uibutton-with-imageedgeinsets-and-titleedgeinsets) but folks suggest to manually set offset to 10 using UIEdgeInsetsMake. Is there solution like - say to button that we dont want vertical offsets? Thanks

Comment: I guess setting explicitly button's height is not what you are looking for, is it?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ not really I just want to remove any of vertical offsets