# Swift: Radio button into StackView are not displayed properly

Tags: ios, swift, stackview

I created a list of radio button in a stackView, but I do not understand why they are displayed wrong, they are not properly aligned

I want all my buttons to be correctly aligned on the left as I can solve this problem thank you!
[image: And here is the result in photo:]

Here is a part of the code:

```
var buttons = [UIButton]()
var titles = ["Lasy", "What I've been told", "I'm do into it", "Close the best i can", "Hard core"]


func setupUI() {

    for title in titles {
        // create button
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck.png")!, for: .normal)

        // if the selected button cannot be reclick again, you can use .Disabled state
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "check.png")!, for: .selected)
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 35)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(radioButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

        buttons.append(button)
    }

    for button in buttons {
        addArrangedSubview(button)
    }

    setupUserChoice()
}

func setupUserChoice(){
    if titles.contains(value) {
        let valueIndex = titles.index(of: value)

        radioButtonAction(sender: buttons[valueIndex!])
    }
}

func setStackView() {
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.spacing = 16.0
    stackView.alignment = .leading
}
```

Comment: this issue happening only when the button is selected?

Comment: not look at the penultimate example for example he is also not aligned. it looks like it's 1 out of 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the way you are trying to set the **imageEdgeInsets**. It is only adjusting the image position, not increasing the size of the button accordingly. For increasing the size of the button, you need to set **contentEdgeInsets**. But you also need to adjust the title position according to the change in image's position. You can use **titleEdgeInsets** for that.

So remove you code `button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 35)` and replace it with :-

```
let leftPadding_beforeImage: CGFloat = 35
let gapBetweenImageAndTitle: CGFloat = 8
let rightPadding_afterTitle: CGFloat = 16

button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, leftPadding_beforeImage, 0, 0)
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, (leftPadding_beforeImage+gapBetweenImageAndTitle), 0, -(leftPadding_beforeImage+gapBetweenImageAndTitle))
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, (leftPadding_beforeImage+gapBetweenImageAndTitle+rightPadding_afterTitle))
```

I hope the variable names are self-explanatory. If you want to know more about UIButton edgeInsets, I suggest you reading [this fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25559946/4637057).

Comment: Thamks my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Set the frame of each button, because `UIStackView`s use intrinsic content size. for example :

```
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20)
```