# The space between title and text on UIButton is not correct when adjusting titleEdgeInsets and imageEdgeInsets

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to adjust the space between text and image on UIButton,

```swift
let space = 10
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: space, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

[image]

It looks well, the space in the picture is absolutely 10.

And now, I want them center,

```swift
let space = 10
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: space, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

[image]

It looks much smaller, and the space is only 5. I find it from Reveal.

**Why the space is reduced by half?**

I searched, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5358259/4789773) tells me how to make title and image center as a single entity. And it adjust their space like this:

```swift
CGFloat spacing = 10; // the amount of spacing to appear between image and title
tabBtn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, spacing);
tabBtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, spacing, 0, 0);
```

Yes, it truly works well, but why? From the letter, the space should be 20, doesn't it?

[Here](https://github.com/ingocraft/ButtonInsetsExample) is an example, any helps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Didn't set `imageEdgeInsets` like this :

```
rightButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 10)
```

So total Code is here :

```
leftButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
        leftButton.imageView?.backgroundColor = .red
        leftButton.titleLabel?.backgroundColor = .gray
        leftButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        rightButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
        rightButton.imageView?.backgroundColor = .red
        rightButton.titleLabel?.backgroundColor = .gray
        rightButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 10)
        rightButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

**Reason:** 
Actually you need to set `imageEdgeInsets` both time left alignment or center alignment 
But when its left alignment image there is no space to set Insets at the right side.

Seet this code :

```
leftButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 100)
```

Here is also no space .

So home you get some idea how insets work :

For your more Help :

[Click here](https://medium.com/short-swift-stories/using-uiedgeinsets-to-layout-a-uibutton-44ba04dd085c)