# Custom UIButton imageEdgeInsets/titleEdgeInsets not working

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

The `imegEdgeInsets` and `titleEdgeInsets` are not working for my custom `UIButton` class.
I'm setting the insets via nib

[image]

[image].

Custom `UIButton` class code

```
class FilledButton: kButton {
    private var bgColor = AppTonalPalette.color(.primary)
    private var bgColorPressed = AppTonalPalette.color(.primary).withAlphaComponent(0.88)
    private var foregroundColor = AppTonalPalette.color(.onPrimary)
    
    private var bgColorDisabled = UIColor.init("#1F1F1F", alpha: 0.12)
    private var foregroundColorDisabled = AppTonalPalette.color(.onSurface)
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateViews()
    }
    
    func updateViews() {
        tintColor = isEnabled ? foregroundColor : foregroundColorDisabled
        setTitleColor(isEnabled ? foregroundColor : foregroundColorDisabled, for: .normal)
        setTitleColor(isEnabled ? foregroundColor : foregroundColorDisabled, for: .highlighted)
        backgroundColor = isEnabled ? (isHighlighted ? bgColorPressed : bgColor) : bgColorDisabled
    }
}

class kButton: UIButton {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        setup()
    }
    
    func setup() {
        titleLabel?.font = AppFont.fontOf(size: 14, style: .Regular)
        setNeedsLayout()
    }
}
```

I've also tried adding insets in mu custom class code like:

```
    func updateViews() {
        tintColor = isEnabled ? foregroundColor : foregroundColorDisabled
        setTitleColor(isEnabled ? foregroundColor : foregroundColorDisabled, for: .normal)
        setTitleColor(isEnabled ? foregroundColor : foregroundColorDisabled, for: .highlighted)
        backgroundColor = isEnabled ? (isHighlighted ? bgColorPressed : bgColor) : bgColorDisabled
        
        if imageView?.image != nil {
            imageEdgeInsets = .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 10)
            titleEdgeInsets = .init(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        }
    }
```

But still the same. What is missing here?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? I tried your insets on a standard UIButton with an image – it looks as yours. Take a look at this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564621/aligning-text-and-image-on-uibutton-with-imageedgeinsets-and-titleedgeinsets It might be helpful for understanding how to achieve different insets in cases like yours.

Comment: @lazarevzubov I want some space between title and image

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try changing button style to default via buttons attribute inspector.

[image]

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: how to set it by code?