# storyboard positioning text below image inside a button

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I am able to set the image and text for button. But it is aligned horizontally. I want the image and text to be aligned vertically inside the button. i.e., text below the image

How to make these changes using storyboard?

What I want is this:

[image]

What I am getting now is this:
[image]

Comment: not clear what are you asking :(

Comment: Please post an image if you can to explain what you want.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451223/uibutton-how-to-center-an-image-and-a-text-using-imageedgeinsets-and-titleedgei

Comment: works fine with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/59666154/1576134

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes you can do it from storyboard without writing any logic also.

1) Select button and go to `Attribute Inspector` in your storyboard.

2) Assign Image to the button. (Don't use background Image)

3) Set Title text to that button.

4) Now you need to set `edge` and `Inset` so first select image from edge and set Inset as you need and then select title from edge and set inset as per your need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understood. But I didnt flow this. because this is not works some times. title will very big means alignment will be vary. How to handle that issue?

Comment: So, I used created a new subclass of UIView with image and label with tag gesture

Comment: works fine with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/59666154/1576134

Answer (score 48):

If you are looking for output like this

[image: Button Image with Text]

1) Select button and go to **Attribute Inspector** in your storyboard to get this result of Button size 50*50

[image]

2) Now set Title Insets of Button

[image]

Comment: In Xcode 8.2.1 with Storyboard, I am not able to find that option for TitleInsets.

Comment: @DShah I have updated my answer with new image please check. Now you will easily found the Title Instests

Answer (score 30):

I've written an extension that do the works for you, **Swift 4** compatible.

```
public extension UIButton {

    func alignTextBelow(spacing: CGFloat = 6.0) {
        if let image = self.imageView?.image {
            let imageSize: CGSize = image.size
            self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(spacing, -imageSize.width, -(imageSize.height), 0.0)
            let labelString = NSString(string: self.titleLabel!.text!)
            let titleSize = labelString.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: self.titleLabel!.font])
            self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-(titleSize.height + spacing), 0.0, 0.0, -titleSize.width)
        }
    }

}
```

Where `spacing` is the distance between image and text.

Comment: Yes it does. A little correction though: let imageSize = self.imageView!.frame.size

Comment: titleEdgeInsets must be set to this: self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(imageSize.height + spacing, -imageSize.width, -(imageSize.height), 0.0)

Comment: it's a nice solution

Comment: Problem with this solution is if I change the text dynamically, the image moves left and right depending on the text. How do I keep image stable while accounting for maximum title size height?

Comment: The other problem with this solution and I've tried similar ones to this is, it's breaking Layout Constraints and the console is going bonkers with all the broken constraints.

Answer (score 9):

You can easily and visually achieve the alignment using the `Edge` property of the Button from **Property Window(Attribute Inspector)** you can change the `inset` values of `Title`, and `Image` as per your need, see image below

[image]

Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4.2 compatible code is here , you just need to call this function

```
  public extension UIButton
  {

    func alignTextUnderImage(spacing: CGFloat = 6.0)
    {
        if let image = self.imageView?.image
        {
            let imageSize: CGSize = image.size
            self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: -imageSize.width, bottom: -(imageSize.height), right: 0.0)
            let labelString = NSString(string: self.titleLabel!.text!)
            let titleSize = labelString.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: self.titleLabel!.font])
            self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -(titleSize.height + spacing), left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: -titleSize.width)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a refined one

```
func alignTextUnderImage(spacing: CGFloat = 6.0) {
    guard let image = imageView?.image, let label = titleLabel,
      let string = label.text else { return }

      titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: -image.size.width, bottom: -image.size.height, right: 0.0)
      let titleSize = string.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: label.font])
      imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -(titleSize.height + spacing), left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: -titleSize.width)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @rbiard. Another workaround when you are developing a multilingual mobile app and when using UISemanticContentAttribute (right to left and left to right). This should work:

```
func alignTextBelow(spacing: CGFloat = 10.0) {
    guard
        let image = imageView?.image,
        let label = titleLabel,
        let string = label.text
    else { return }

    let titleSize = string.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: label.font])
    
    //when the selected language is English
    if L102Language.currentAppleLanguage() == "en" {      
        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: -image.size.width, bottom: -image.size.height, right: 0)
        imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -(titleSize.height + spacing), left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: -titleSize.width)
    } else {
        //When selecting a right to left language. For example, Arabic            
        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: 0, bottom: -image.size.height, right: -image.size.width)
        imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -(titleSize.height + spacing), left: -titleSize.width, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `Attribute Inspector` in storyboard

1. Setup button size
2. Setup image's top
3. Setup title's top and left
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

You cannot change layout directly in UIButton, but you can try to use these properties on UIButton:

```
UIButton *button = ...
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(....);
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(....);
```

If it won't help I'd recommend to subclass from UIResponder and make your own component and do your own layout as you needed it.