# What is the ideal place to set edge insets of UIButton when its subview of a UITableViewCell or subview of Any other View

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, layoutsubviews

I have a scenario where I need to change UIEdgeInsets for UIButton which is added to the UITableViewCell, I set it in layoutSubviews but that's called a number of times, it also work's with init too but I am not sure that's really a place because that will called only once.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if imageView != nil {
            titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 52, left: -10, bottom: 0, right:-10)
        }
    }
```

Can someone tell me which one is **the ideal place and why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` will be called when a new cell is loaded from a xib or storyboard
, but not when a cell is re-used.
**But** during awakeFromNib the frame layouts do not appear . `UIEdgeInsets` will not effected by frame so i prefer to call it at  awakeFromNib not in 
layoutSubviews

`layoutSubviews` you will get correct frame so used only with stylish that need correct frame like corner radius

Comment: So you mean UIEdgeInsets never changes even if the super and self-view frame changes as this button only show when needed and have title below the image? My concern this because most of the people suggest to setup this in layoutSubview like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201959/label-under-image-in-uibutton, my button is subclass and added programmatically.

Comment: UIEdgeInsets not effected by Button frame it just inset from frame what ever this frame is

Answer (score 0):

Use `awakeFromNib()` if you use `xib`.

It call one time and this from documentation to `awakeFromNib()`:

> Typically, you implement awakeFromNib for objects that require additional set up that cannot be done at design time. For example, you might use this method to customize the default configuration of any controls to match user preferences or the values in other controls. You might also use it to restore individual controls to some previous state of your application.

Or if you don't use `xib` just use init because it called once.