# How can I format text in Swift to the bottom?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiimage

I am making an app where I need text to display directly above a UIImage. When the text is too wide to fit, I need it to display on 2 rows of text, with the bottom one being at the same position vertically as if it only had one row. If the text cannot fit in two rows, I want it to get smaller so that it will just fit in the two rows. Below is an image showing what I mean.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKuA6.png)

Comment: add current code you are using, normally setting numberOfLines on UILabel is enough

Comment: See this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201959/label-under-image-in-uibutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Label constraints : top to superview , leading & trailing & bottom to imageView ,,, with .lines = 2 , textAlignment = .center

ImageView constraints : centerX , width , height